# Can IIS7 unzip Gzipped file during upload

Tags: iis-7, compression

I have a mvc3 projects with bunch of restful apis. After enabling compression on IIS7, I can download gzipped files.

I am wondering a scenario the other way. I uploaded a bunch of gzipped files with some headers, IIS will decompress the files and save them on the server? Did anyone hear something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

Look at a zip library such as [SharpZipLib](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/12.aspx) to perform the decompression.